# Propagate headers in Java microservice through Agent

Tags: java, http-headers, javaagents, open-telemetry, distributed-tracing

We have many microservices in the system. I want to build a Java library to propagate auth tokens to each service request.

1. I can intercept HHTP headers and write a custom interceptor for each client like RestTemplate, WebClient to inject headers. The problem here is it I have to write for each request library and then ask service owners to inject this interceptor.
2. I got to know about open telemetry ([Java auto instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation)). Is there a way to add custom headers either in source code or implement some class and build a new agent which can be integrated into all microservices running in Java?